# Appending an entry in one to many embedded document mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am new to MongoDB and I came across the following use case:

Lets say I have my mongodb document like this:

```
{
    _id: "joe",
    name: "Joe Bookreader",
    numbers: [
                {
                    mobile: 741134217,
                },
                {
                    home: 123452411
                }
            ]
}
```

Now I need to two perform two operations:

1. Add a new number `{office:112342282}`
2. Delete users home number

I believe that we can do this in Mongo, but I am not getting the syntax anywhere, neither I could find it in the MongoDB documentation.

P.S. I am doing this using Monk Library, monk specific syntax would be of great help. But otherwise also it would help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is Mongo's [$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) and [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator

You **should be able to** do it by doing the following:

```
db.User.update({_id: 'joe'}, {$push: {numbers: {office: 112342282}}, $pull: {numbers: {home: 123452411}}});
```

Unfortunately, Mongo doesn't let you operate on the same field with both the `$push` and `$pull` operators at the same time (see [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050)). So it really needs to be:

```
db.User.update({_id: 'joe'}, { $push: { numbers:  { office: 112342282}}})
db.User.update({_id: 'joe'}, { $pull: { numbers: {home: 123452411}}})
```

Using monk's style:

```
var users = db.get('users');
users.update({_id: 'joe'}, { $push: { numbers:  { office: 112342282}}})
users.update({_id: 'joe'}, { $pull: { numbers: {home: 123452411}}})
```